# boost library and held value

Tags: c++, boost, boost-any

I have been using `boost` for a while but am still a novice. 
I think I fall for `boost::any` as I don't need to use template much anymore to handle typed objects used or returned.
Yet one thing I find it still inconvenient to me is a smoother function or method if any to transfer its `held` data back and forth succinctly and certainly without later use of `cast_any`.

Convention

```
(case 1)
boost::any a="123456";
std::string s=boost::cast_any<std::string>(a);
(case 2)
boost:any a=123456;
int i=boost::cast_any<int>a;
```

Custom boost_any:

```
(case 1)
boost:any a="123456";
std::string s=a;
(case 2)
boost:any a=123456;
int i=a;
```

I like this feature because during debugging my program I find the object's `held="123456"` exactly the same in both cases. I `think` the internal implementation of the lib might have done that (converted the content it is holding into `string`).
This example only shows POD types, I'd like to know if anyone has done anything about this customization or ways to achieve the same result for me to eliminate the `cast_any`.

Answer (score 0):

Boost.Any is a specialized tool, usually for hiding user-supplied data in library types. It's not a general-purpose "forget types, I have any" system. It doesn't work that way, because in the end you have to cast to a specific type anyway.

Hiding the `any_cast` behind an implicit conversion is a bad idea because it will throw if the wrong type is stored. Having that in a simple assignment would be a great source of hard-to-find bugs.

Anyway, the debugging support for `any` is totally separate from any real code and won't help you in achieving what you want. If you really want the implicit conversion, you need to add a templated conversion operator to the `any` class. But I strongly advise against it, and against overuse of `any` in general. In most cases, it doesn't actually help, or other solutions are superior. Don't be afraid of templates.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::any` is implemented in the type-safe spirit of C++. Run-time efficiency and strong typing are the constraints behind its design. Although it provides a mechanism for dynamic type discovery, `boost::any` does not itself get involved into such activity, nor is it willing to cooperate in implicit conversions between values of different types.

Anyway there are other implementations of `any` (e.g [`Poco::DynamicAny`](http://pocoproject.org/)) that extend `boost::any` functionality (implicit conversion to target type when possible/safe and many other features).

A very interesting article about this topic is [DynamicAny (Overload Journal #86 - August 2008 -  Aleksandar Fabijanic)](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1502)